# ¿Como mostrar un contador de registros?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, php5

Estoy realizando un contador de registros, Pero no me está mostrando la cantidad total de los registros. ¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Aquí realizo la conexión

```
require_once '../Controlador/conexion.php';
$objeto = new Conexion();
$conexion = $objeto->Conectar();
```

Aqui hago el procedimiento para que me muestre la cantidad de registros, pero solo me muestra uno

```
<?php 

    $consulta = "SELECT id FROM reportes WHERE estatus = 1 ";
    $resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
    $resultado->execute();
    $data = $resultado->fetchColumn();
    echo '<h4> Total: ' . $data . '</h4>';

?>
```

Solo me esta mostrando un registro, cuando debería de ponerme dos.

[image: Registros]

[image: Total de registros]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si quieres contar las filas que cumplan el criterio de tu consulta, deberías escribir una instrucción del tipo `COUNT(*)`. Por ejemplo:

```
$consulta = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reportes WHERE estatus = 1";
$resultado = $conexion->prepare($consulta)->execute();
$data = $resultado->fetchColumn();
echo "<h4> Total: $data</h4>";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciono.

Comment: @AndrésdeJesús Me alegro. Recuerda que en PHP, si usas comillas dobles, puedes meter variables dentro, así el código queda más claro. Y también, con PDO puedes encadenar métodos, por eso puse `prepare()->execute()`

Comment: Si eso vi, Excelente. Soy nuevo programando y poco a poco voy adquiriendo experiencia. En verdad muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: aunque, me manda un error al final cuando coloco $data = $resultado->fetchColumn(); me manda erorr en $resultado.

Comment: @AndrésdeJesús ¿qué error manda?

Comment: Me marca erorr en la variable $resultado

Comment: ¿Pero qué error, @AndrésdeJesús, de sintaxis u otro tipo de error?

Comment: ya sé por qué, ya lo corregí, Gracias :)